# Swift arrays identity "Type does not conform to protocol 'AnyObject'" error

Tags: arrays, swift, identity, swift-playground

I create playground and write this code:

```
var a = [1, 2, 3]
var b = a

a === b
```

And playground gives me error `Type '[Int]' does not conform to protocol 'AnyObject'`.

What am I doing wrong?

I'm using XCode 6 GM Seed.

**UPDATE**

This code was taken from "The Swift Programming Language" book that states:

```
“Check whether two arrays or subarrays share the same storage and elements by comparing them with the identity operators (=== and !==).”
```

in "Classes and Structures" chapter.

**UPDATE 2**
The excerpt was from old version of book for early Swift specification. I downloaded the fresh one and there is no such words. So identity operators can be applied only to class instances.

Comment: I can't find this excerpt in the last update of the _Swift Programming Language_.

Comment: Damn it! That was an old copy! I redownloaded it in iBooks and there is no such excerpt :(  Does iBooks automatically redownload books if they were updated or I have to redownload in manually?

Comment: In the [updated document](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ClassesAndStructures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH13-XID_135) it states "Use these operators to check whether two constants or variables refer to the same single instance:".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to *The Swift Programing Language*:

> ”Identical to” [represented by three equals signs, or ===] means that two constants or variables of class type
>   refer to exactly the same class instance.

In Swift, Arrays are Structs. Therefore, you can't try to use `===` to compare one Array to another one. Otherwise, the following code - using NSArray - works fine and does not give any error message in Playground:

```
var a = [1, 2, 3] as NSArray //NSArray is not a Struct
var b = a
a === b //true
```

The explanation of this is given by *The Swift Programing Language*:

> Structure instances are always passed by value, and  class instances
>   are always passed by reference.

Of course, **Identical to** (===) has not the same goal than **Equal to** (==) which helps you to check that two instances are considered “equal” or “equivalent” in value. For example, the following code will compile in Playground without any error message:

```
var a = [1, 2, 3]
var b = a
a == b //true
```

Comment: I totally agree with you. But the same book states that I can use `===` to "check  whether two arrays or subarrays share the same storage and elements". See my update to question.

Answer (score 2):

`===` is identical to operator and available only for class instances. An array is structure so there is no function for this operator. I could agree that error message is not descriptive enough in this case.

Use `==` to compare arrays for equality.

Comment: I can not use `==` for arrays which contains objects. Please, sees my update. May be Apple changed Swift specification?

Comment: Cannot find that quote in the book.

Comment: I have an old version in iBooks. Redownloaded and there is no such quote.